# JDBC batchUpdate with SQL update statement very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

We have a simple update query like so :

```
UPDATE orders SET quantity=?, price=? WHERE orderSerialNo=?
```

`orderSerialNo` is not a primary key but is unique and we have an index on it.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_orders_sno ON orders (orderSerialNo);
```

Java code to update quantity and price in bulk :

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SYNC_ORDER_QUERY, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                final SyncData sd = syncDataList.get(i);
                ps.setLong(1, sd.getQuantity());
                ps.setInt(2, sd.getPrice());
                ps.setString(3, sd.getOrderSerialNo());
            }

            @Override public int getBatchSize() {
                return syncDataList.size();
            }
        });
```

A batch of just 1000 orders is taking over 20 mins to update. We can't just figure out why. Oracle was up all the time. What can be the problem here?

When I execute a single update statement from SQL developer it executes in .03 secs which is fast I think.
The `Explain Plan` shows a cost of 2. The above index is used with a `RANGE SCAN` option and cost 1.

Comment: What did you analyze so far? Does the same update command require the same time when it will be executed directly in SQL Developer or SQL Plus? Did you try out to restrict it on 10 or on 100 rows?

Comment: Try using `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` in your JDBC connection URL.

Comment: Added more analysis. Let me check what rewriteBatchedStatements=true does.

Comment: You may find session id for your connection and use `dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor` to find an actual execution plan that was used and identify slow operations if any.